# Composer laravel new app doesn't generate other files

Tags: php, laravel

Hello so the first time I used laravel 5 went great, I just use `laravel new app_name` and everything is fine. Now whenever I create a new app again, some files are not generated. I looked at my files and the `css, fonts` folder is missing in the `public` folder. The `auth` folder in `views` is also missing. As far as I remember, I didn't do anything. Any thoughts on how to create a new app in laravel with all these files/folders included?

Comment: You can create them. Laravel 5.1 does not contain them by default. See the documentation for more info.

Comment: Im just copy pasting from the original file I created for now.

Comment: @chanafdo Link for the documentation to create them..?

Comment: You can create the css, js or anything you need inside the `public` folder. For the `auth` views you can refer [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-views)